# How to insert space in url for sitemap node asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xml, sitemap

I have a space and when i write the url in sitemap as it's look like in the browser it give me error : **The 'url' property had a malformed URL** ,
 I also try **%20** and still not work

Comment: Can you give the url that is make the error ? and how exactly you have it on file...

Comment: You may try + instead of %20. You might also escape the space with a backslash. You may also try HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode() or Uri.EscapeUriString().

Comment: <siteMapNode url="~/CategoryPage.aspx?name=Get Well" title="Get Well"/>

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace a whitespace with "**& nbsp;**" code. E.g.:

```
~/CategoryPage.aspx?name=Get&nbsp;Well
```

Answer (score 0):

For sitemaps, the convention is simple :

use "+" or "%20" in the query-string, use "%20" within the rest of the URL.﻿